# Compare pandas column values with words in textfile using regular expressions

Tags: python, pandas, match, python-re

I have a `df` dataframe like this:

```
product      name     description0 description1 description2 description3
  A          plane         flies        air      passengers     wings
  B          car           rolls        road        NaN          NaN
  C          boat          floats       sea      passengers      NaN
```

What I want to do is to compare for each value in description columns to be searched in a txt file.

Let's say my `test.txt` file is:

He `flies` to London then crosses the `sea` to reach New-York.

The result would look like this:

```
product      name     description0 description1 description2 description3 Match
  A          plane         flies        air      passengers     wings     Match
  B          car           rolls        road        NaN          NaN      No match
  C          boat          floats       sea      passengers      NaN      Match
```

I know the main structure but I'm a bit lost for the rest

```
with open ("test.txt", 'r') as searchfile:
    for line in searchfile:
        print line
        if re.search() in line:
            print(match)
```

Comment: 1. Is the match case-sensitive or not? 2. Is `seaweed` also a match of `sea`? 3. Is `... sea.` also a match for `sea`? 4. What have you tried?

Comment: 1.The match is not case-sensitive.
2 and 3. It can be.
4.I am going to update my post with my try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the input text using `str.find()` since you are searching for string literals. `re.search()` seems to be an overkill.

A quick-and-dirty solution using `.apply(axis=1)`:

### Data

```
# df as given
input_text = "He flies to London then crosses the sea to reach New-York."
```

### Code

```
input_text_lower = input_text.lower()

def search(row):
    for el in row:  # description 0,1,2,3
        #  skip non-string contents and if the search is successful
        if isinstance(el, str) and (input_text_lower.find(el.lower()) >= 0):
            return True
    return False

df["Match"] = df[[f"description{i}" for i in range(4)]].apply(search, axis=1)
```

### Result

```
print(df)
  product   name description0 description1 description2 description3  Match
0       A  plane        flies          air   passengers        wings   True
1       B    car        rolls         road          NaN          NaN  False
2       C   boat       floats          sea   passengers          NaN   True
```

### Note

Word boundary, punctuation and hyphens are not considered in the original problem. In real cases, additional preprocessing steps is likely to be required. This is out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: The code works correctly as expected thank you. Do you know what variations I could do in case description contains more than one word (and says that there is a match even if only one word is detected)?

Comment: As a quick-and-dirty fix, you can add `for word in el.split(): ` after `for el in row:`, and replace subsequent `el` by `word`. In addition, I'd suggest NOT splitting up the question like this. Just give the corner cases as much as you can, or both parties will be wasting time in follow-up discussions like this. Stating a complex demand is not a problem. Only "unclear" or "undisclosed" statements are.

Comment: I understand your point of view. Thank you for your help.